# Enable raster visualisation parameters panel in Google Earth Engine App

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

In the code editor of Google Earth Engine are several visualisation parameters per layer (can be access via the settings icon in the layer panel). When I publish the app as a GEE app, there is no such options. Can I enable them somewhere?

[image]

Comment: I don't think you can activate this option on the app. What you can do is to add a panel where you can input the visualization parameters that you want to modify. And then update the visualization using the input parameters